# Potential Energy for Atoms other than Hydrogen like Species

Tags: particle-physics

I know that Potential Energy of an Hydrogen like species = -1/4πé . e²/r² but I have question that What is the formula to find Potential Energy of other Atoms like Oxygen , Xenon ..? Is there a way to find Potential Energy of atoms / molecules other than H Like Species ?

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Comment: It's a perfectly good question, and the answer is that yes we can calculate the energy of an atom with more than ne electron, but it's a hard calculation that has to be done by computer. See the question I've linked for the details.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRennie ! I found it Very Useful .